# writing with python into a csv file with multiple lines in one cell

Tags: python, selenium

im using writer.writerow(groupOfUsers) where groupOfUsers is a list of users 
ex: ['joe','john','jane']
i want all 3 names printed with a new line into one cell but with the current command it writes the 3 names into 3 different new rows

i want it to look like 
joe
john
jane

and not

joe

---

john

---

jane

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to send it an array of size 1 if you want your entries in a single row. You could pass `["joe"\n"john"\n"jane"]` with code like this:

```
writer.writerow(["\n".join(['joe','john','jane'])])
```

And for extra clarity:

```
In [2]: ["\n".join(['joe','john','jane'])]
Out[2]: ['joe\njohn\njane']
```

Comment: thanks so much! this lead to me to the right answer, which was adding an extra '\r', making it '\r\n' which makes them multi-line and \n just puts them on the same line